# intel hd graphics 3000, reduce shared memory allocation

Tags: memory, graphics-card

I cant find the way to reduce the video shared memory size.  Is it possible?

I have searched all configurations on the driver.  I have also disabled the driver.  I have searched the bios with no luck (which I have set to 32MB, I do not remember the option's name but the only one related to video)

I am not a gamer, so I want 128Mb of shared memory and free 1Gb to the system.

[image]

Comment: x86 or x64 Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound x86 windows

Comment: The shared memory cannot be reduced.  If you have a dedecated GPU you can disable the device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile Intel Intergrated Graphics - Changing Shared Graphics Memory?](http://superuser.com/questions/36586/mobile-intel-intergrated-graphics-changing-shared-graphics-memory)